# WebClient.DownloadString() Is not working inside thread

Tags: c#, json, multithreading, httprequest, webclient

I have a class which contains the code

**Code:**

```
public class getStringClass
{
   public void getMyJson()
   {
      Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(takeit));
      t.IsBackground = true;
      t.Start();
   }

   public void takeit()
   {
      string jsonResult = "Cannot Connect! Try Later.";
      try
      {

         using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
         {
            string url = "some url goes here";
            jsonResult = client.DownloadString(url); //url contains API to get json response, and its valid ,providing json when i checks with browser.
         }
      }
      catch
      {
      }
      MessageBox.Show(jsonResult);
   }
}
```

No Exception Occurring when i catch the exception and prints the ex.Message. This code works directly when i use inside some button clicks event of the Form.cs and providing correct **response string**.

```
buttonGetJson_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    getStringClass clsObj = new getStringClass();
    clsObj.getMyJson();     
}
```

But the problem is if i have a class (for example demo.cs) inside my solution and i am calling this getMyJson() from demo class followed by creating object of getStringClass, its not printing the response string, it will always print the default message "Cannot Connect! Try Later."

**Example Code**

```
public class demo
{
    public void callJson()
    {
        getStringClass objCls = new getStringClass();
        objCls.getMyJson();
    }
}
```

what is the problem here ?  should i change the WebClient ? Is There Any Problem When using a Thread inside a class? Or is it not correct approach of calling a thread? Same problem exist when i use backgroundworker too.

Comment: Where is your `url` variable being set? By looking at your class it doesn't look like it should compile.

Comment: URL will be passed by argument

Comment: Is the new Thread still running getMyJson()? (The new thread is also creating a thread?)

Comment: Should i use Thread t = new Thread(functionCall) ?

Comment: As far as I can tell there is no need to create another thread.    I also got my sample running with below addition to you code            IWebProxy defaultWebProxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;
                defaultWebProxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

                WebClient clien = new WebClient { Proxy = defaultWebProxy };

Comment: Obviously an exception _is_ occurring. If you'd bother to catch the exception object and examine it, it would most likely tell you exactly what you want to know. In any case, since you didn't bother to provide a good [mcve] that reproduces your problem, we can't.

Comment: @SeckinCelik  should i add `IWebProxy defaultWebProxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy; defaultWebProxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials; WebClient clien = new WebClient { Proxy = defaultWebProxy };` inside my request part ?

Comment: @PeterDuniho there is no exception found! when i use exception object and examine the exception message, its not firing any exception

Comment: _"when i use exception object and examine the exception message, its not firing any exception"_ -- that makes no sense. How can you "examine the exception message" if there is no exception? In any case, it is not possible for the code you've posted to show `"Cannot Connect! Try Later."` as the result unless there is an exception.

Comment: @PeterDuniho what i meant is if any exception goes it will be catches. Look at the code i have given above, i just removed the `catch(Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }` when i add these lines, it does not fire any exception messages.

Comment: Please, oh Lord, stop programmers from writing `catch { }`...

Comment: Oh Why ? @Enigmativity

Comment: @LazyProgramer - It's just such a good way to swallow exceptions and make debugging super hard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code:

```
    public void takeit()
    {
        string jsonResult = "Cannot Connect! Try Later.";
        try
        {
            IWebProxy defWebProxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;
            defWebProxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

            WebClient clien = new WebClient { Proxy = defWebProxy };

            jsonResult = clien.DownloadString("http://www.google.com");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            jsonResult = ex.StackTrace;
        }
        MessageBox.Show(jsonResult);
    }
```

Comment: i think this line `using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                string url = "http://www.google.com";
                jsonResult = client.DownloadString(url); 
            }` you forgot to comment ?

Comment: Anyway Without webProxy webclient does not download string from URL ? This error because of proxy or any other Thread Issue ?

Comment: @LazyProgrammer Yes it is a proxy issue not a thread. When there is a proxy server you need to set proxy credentials.